# Python lists comparing and merging

Tags: python, list, compare

I have 2 lists:

```
correct_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
other_list = [4,5,6,7,8,10]
```

I would like to combine these two lists so:

```
combined_list = [{k:1, v:0},{k:2, v:0},{k:3, v:0}, {k:4, v:4}, {etc}]
```

so basically am saying that the key is the correct list, and where ever the other_list does not match the correct_list, fill in a 0, or " " . And of they do match, fill in the matching value

Does this makes sense ?

How would I do this in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[{'k': c, 'v': c if c in other_list else 0} for c in correct_list]
```

By the way, if the only elements of the dictionaries are k and v, consider building a dictionary instead of a list of dictionaries:

```
>>> dict((c, c if c in other_list else 0) for c in correct_list)
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 0, 10: 10}
```

Comment: Cool, this works! thanks, now just one thing, the list is sorted correctly, but not the dict ?why is this ?

Comment: @Harry dicts are unordered. Replace `dict` with [`collections.orderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if order matters, or stick with your original solution.

Comment: How would I go about to give v: the value of the other_list value, and not the value of the correct_list ?

Comment: @Harry Replace `c if c in other_list else 0` with a helper function that goes through all objects of other_list, compares them to the `c` at hand, and picks the right one.